# Constructing a grid from a matrix

Tags: graphics, matrix, visualization

I would like to construct a grid from a matrix. For example, one possible matrix is $M1$.

$$M1=
\begin{pmatrix}
c2 & a1 & a1 & a1 & a1 & a1\\
a2 & b1 & c2 & a1 & a1 & a1\\
a2 & c2 & b2 & a1 & a1 & a1\\
b2 & b2 & c1 & b1 & c2 & a1\\
b2 & c1 & b1 & c2 & b2 & a1\\
a2 & b1 & b1 & a2 & a2 & c2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Each element $a1, a2, \dots, c2$ is represented graphically as the following:
[image: 6vertex]

So I want to represent $M1$ as:

[image: grid representation]

Here, how an element, $c2$ fits in the grid is shown as an example.
Is this possible in *Mathematica*? Currently, I have no idea even where to begin. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I see that you have already Accepted an answer but I hope you will give consideration to my code as well.  I feel that it is ultimately a cleaner approach with less code duplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define $a_1,a_2$,.. as graphic primitives (Line) and use `Translate`:

```
a1 = {Thickness[.01], Line[{{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}}}]};
a2 = {Line[{{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}}}]};
b1 = {Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], Thickness[.01], Line[{{1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}}]};
b2 = {Line[{{1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}}], Thickness[.01], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]};
c1 = {Line[{{{1/2, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{1/2, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}}}], 
      Thickness[.01], 
      Line[{{{0, 0}, {1/2, 0}}, {{1/2, 0}, {1/2, -1/2}}}]};
c2 = {Line[{{{0, 0}, {1/2, 0}}, {{1/2, 0}, {1/2, -1/2}}}], 
      Thickness[.01], 
      Line[{{{1/2, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{1/2, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}}}]};

m = 
 {{c2, a1, a1, a1, a1, a1}, {a2, b1, c2, a1, a1, a1},
  {a2, c2, b2, a1, a1, a1}, {b2, b2, c1, b1, c2, a1}, 
  {b2, c1, b1, c2, b2, a1}, {a2, b1, b1, a2, a2, c2}};

Graphics[
 MapIndexed[
  Translate[#1, Reverse[#2]] &, Reverse[m], {2}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: beat me to it; +1

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing that is create an image for each element and then use `GraphicsGrid`

With the definition about `line` of @halmir

```
a1 = {Thickness[.03], Line[{{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}}}]};
a2 = {Line[{{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}}}]};
b1 = {Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], Thickness[.03], Line[{{1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}}]};
b2 = {Line[{{1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}}], Thickness[.03], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]};
c1 = {Line[{{{1/2, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{1/2, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}}}], 
      Thickness[.03], 
      Line[{{{0, 0}, {1/2, 0}}, {{1/2, 0}, {1/2, -1/2}}}]};
c2 = {Line[{{{0, 0}, {1/2, 0}}, {{1/2, 0}, {1/2, -1/2}}}], 
      Thickness[.03], 
      Line[{{{1/2, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{1/2, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}}}]};


imgs = Graphics /@ {a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2};
{a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2} = 
  ImageResize[#, {100, 100}] & /@ (ImageCrop[#] & /@ imgs)
```

> [image]

```
M1 = 
{{c2, a1, a1, a1, a1, a1}, {a2, b1, c2, a1, a1, a1},
 {a2, c2, b2, a1, a1, a1}, {b2, b2, c1, b1, c2, a1}, 
 {b2, c1, b1, c2, b2, a1}, {a2, b1, b1, a2, a2, c2}};

GraphicsGrid[M1, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

> [image]

Or:

```
ImageAssemble[M1]
```

> same result

Comment: It would be great if you could make this code executable; you could insert the needed images into your post, then add code with `Import` to bring them into *Mathematica*.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I don't  how to copy this code. when I do it returns a lot of things in low level coding because of the pictures

Comment: I know; you cannot simply copy it as-is.  But perhaps what I was proposing is too much work.  You still have my vote.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Please see my edit:-)

Answer (score 4):

I like the existing answers, but I cannot resist posting my own formulation.  I shall make use of the new-in-10.1 [`CirclePoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePoints.html) though I shall also provide an alternative without it.

First, here are [`Rules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) that specify the thickness of each radial line, counterclockwise from 3 o'clock:

```
rls =
  {"a1" -> {3, 3, 3, 3}, "b1" -> {1, 3, 1, 3}, "c1" -> {1, 1, 3, 3}, 
   "a2" -> {1, 1, 1, 1}, "b2" -> {3, 1, 3, 1}, "c2" -> {3, 3, 1, 1}};
```

And a function that takes a mark and a position:

```
fn[mk_, {r_, c_}] := Thread[{
    AbsoluteThickness /@ (mk /. rls),
    Line[{{c, -r}, #}] & /@ CirclePoints[{c, -r}, {1, 0}, 4]
   }];
```

Your input:

```
m =
 {{"c2", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1"},
  {"a2", "b1", "c2", "a1", "a1", "a1"},
  {"a2", "c2", "b2", "a1", "a1", "a1"},
  {"b2", "b2", "c1", "b1", "c2", "a1"},
  {"b2", "c1", "b1", "c2", "b2", "a1"},
  {"a2", "b1", "b1", "a2", "a2", "c2"}};
```

The operation using [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html):

```
MapIndexed[fn, m, {2}] // Graphics
```

[image: the grid]

If you do not have `CirclePoints` simply use:

```
fn[mk_, {r_, c_}] :=
  Thread[{
    AbsoluteThickness /@ (mk /. rls),
    Line[{{c, -r}, #}] & /@ {{1 + c, -r}, {c, 1 - r}, {c - 1, -r}, {c, -1 - r}}
  }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat different approach:

```
With[{s = 101, (* resolution *) w = 2 (* thickness *)},
     Block[{h = (s + 1)/2},
           rules = {a1 -> Image[SparseArray[{{j_, k_} /; 
                    h - w <= j <= h + w || h - w <= k <= h + w :> 0},
                    {s, s}, 1]],
                    a2 -> Image[SparseArray[{{j_, k_} /; j == h || k == h :> 0},
                    {s, s}, 1]],
                    b1 -> Image[SparseArray[{{j_, k_} /; j == h ||
                                            h - w <= k <= h + w :> 0},
                    {s, s}, 1]], 
                    b2 -> Image[SparseArray[{{j_, k_} /; h - w <= j <= h + w ||
                                            k == h :> 0},
                    {s, s}, 1]],
                    c1 -> Image[SparseArray[{{j_, k_} /; (h - w <= j <= h + w &&
                                            k < h) || (j == h && h <= k) ||
                                            (j <= h && k == h) ||
                                            (h < j && h - w <= k <= h + w) :> 0},
                    {s, s}, 1]], 
                    c2 -> Image[SparseArray[{{j_, k_} /; (j == h && k < h) ||
                                            (h - w <= j <= h + w && h <= k) ||
                                            (j <= h && h - w <= k <= h + w) ||
                                            (h < j && k == h) :> 0},
                    {s, s}, 1]]}]]
```

We can now do this:

```
ImageAssemble[{{c2, a1, a1, a1, a1, a1},
               {a2, b1, c2, a1, a1, a1},
               {a2, c2, b2, a1, a1, a1},
               {b2, b2, c1, b1, c2, a1},
               {b2, c1, b1, c2, b2, a1},
               {a2, b1, b1, a2, a2, c2}} /. rules]
```

[image: grid picture]